# Python datetime and handling microseconds

Tags: python, datetime

So I'd like to preface this by saying that I do not want to use `datetime.strptime()`, I've written a very simple parser and the code is as follows:

```
def datetime_parse(s):
    return datetime.datetime(int(s[0:4]), int(s[5:7]), int(s[8:10]), int(s[11:13]),
                             int(s[14:16]), int(s[17:19]), int(s[20:26]))
```

The issue here is that for my microsecond conversion, I have values such as:

```
2012-09-30 17:00:04.01350000
```

When reading it in `int()` will automatically round down to 0 and as far as I know `datetime.datetime()` will only accept `int`s. Is there a workaround for this?

**Note:** in the original question, which has meanwhile been corrected, the last parameter of `datetime.datetime()` was `int(s[20:27])`.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on why you have your own parser instead of using `datetime.strptime()`?

Comment: I'm computing this over a very large dataset and parsing it this way is significantly faster.

Answer (score 1):

The microsecond should be in the range [0, 1E6). You're passing 7 digits instead of 6, so the extra zero is increasing the actual value by a factor of 10. Try `int(s[20:26])` instead.

Comment: Sorry that was a relic of old code, that's already been adjusted for. The main issue is trying to convert it.

Comment: Reading `s[20:26]` and passing it to an int should automatically convert the value (rounded down to the nearest microsecond). Is there something else you're trying to do?

Comment: So it's values like: .001234 that get rounded down to 0 and I'd prefer to lose that granularity.

Comment: `s[20:26]` will return `'001234'`, which is converted to `1234`. This is what the `datetime_parse` function returns on my machine for your input: `2012-09-30 17:00:04.013500`

Comment: @jma127 is absolutely right. You've lost me... We're only converting the digits after the `.` how can it be rounded down to `0`?

Comment: Ok weird, I just ran it on 2 separate machines and one is returning 2012-09-30 17:00:04.013500 while the other is returning 2012-09-30 17:00:04

Answer (score 1):

It is working as expected - once you parse back to a string you get the same string going in.

```
>>> s = '2012-09-30 17:00:04.013500'
>>> d = datetime.datetime(int(s[0:4]), int(s[5:7]), int(s[8:10]), int(s[11:13]),   int(s[14:16]), int(s[17:19]), int(s[20:26]))
>>> d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
'2012-09-30 17:00:04.013500'
```